# Flutter high images RAM consumption

Tags: performance, flutter

I'm working on an app (mainly for iOS) that contains ListView.builder with lots of pictures (about 64 pictures, 7.7 Mb size in total on disk) and I have a huge performance problem on devices with 1 Gb RAM and lower. I tried to decrease imageCache _maximumSizeBytes to 30 Mb and now the app works better in terms of smoothness but it's bad workaround because now pictures are uploaded from the cache and it leads to freezes in pictures appearing in the list.

Any suggestions/ideas?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.16-pre.88, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale en-RU)
    • Flutter version 1.10.16-pre.88 at /Users/alectogeek/Documents/Programs/flutter
    • Framework revision ff95b14ad8 (30 hours ago), 2019-11-07 23:14:17 -0500
    • Engine revision 7ed9c9fc58
    • Dart version 2.7.0
```

Comment: How are you caching the images?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo Using CachedNetworkImage. Just in case I'll say: CachedNetworkImage caches images from network to local storage. The problem with the framework's RAM caching during runtime.

Comment: Decoded images take a lot of RAM, you should probably make some kind of lazyload or resize images to weigh less.

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin for more than 10 times?

Comment: @alectogeek My jpeg image that has a size about 1Mb on disc takes about 15Mb when loaded with Image.file, so yeah, it can take ways more of RAM.

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin but.. is it normal behavior? Do native iOS apps consume the memory in the same way?

Comment: found an issue related with my question https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32156